# Unit test array from Excel

Tags: c#, .net, unit-testing, xunit.net

I'd like to pass an array from data in an Excel spreadsheet.  Note that I don't want to run a test on each row, but rather one test on the entire list.

As an example, something like this:

```
[Theory]
[ExcelData("test.xls", "select * from [Sheet1$A1:A7]")]
public void TestMyAverage(double[] values)
{
    double desiredResult = values.Average();
    Assert.True(MyAverage(desiredResult));
}
```

However, that particular code won't work because it tries to convert each row (`double`) to a `double[]` causing an error.

Answer (score 1):

I modified the `ExcelDataAttribute` [provided by XUnit](https://github.com/xunit/samples.xunit/blob/master/ExcelDataExample/ExcelDataAttribute.cs).  It hasn't been tested thoroughly, but it seems to work.

There are two new optional parameters:

1. Data contains header (unrelated to this question)
2. Return data as an array

Example usage:

```
[Theory]
[ExcelArrayData("test.xls", "select * from [Sheet1$A1:B7]", false, true)]
public void TestMethod(int[] values, int[] values2)
```

Source Code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.OleDb;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Reflection;
using Xunit.Sdk;

namespace UnitTestCalculationStandards
{
  [AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Method, AllowMultiple = false, Inherited = false)]
  public sealed class ExcelArrayDataAttribute : DataAttribute
  {
    string connectionTemplate =
        "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0; Data Source={0}; Extended Properties='Excel 12.0;HDR=YES;IMEX=1;';";
    public ExcelArrayDataAttribute(string fileName, string queryString, bool hasHeader = true, bool returnAsArray = false)
    {
     // System.Diagnostics.Debugger.Launch();
      if (!hasHeader)
      {
        connectionTemplate = connectionTemplate.Replace("HDR=YES", "HDR=NO");
      }
      FileName = fileName;
      QueryString = queryString;
      ReturnAsArray = returnAsArray;
    }
    public string FileName { get; private set; }
    public string QueryString { get; private set; }
    private bool ReturnAsArray;
    public override IEnumerable<object[]> GetData(MethodInfo testMethod)
    {
      if (testMethod == null)
        throw new ArgumentNullException("testMethod");

      ParameterInfo[] pars = testMethod.GetParameters();

      if (ReturnAsArray)
      {
        return DataSourceAsEnumerable(FileName, QueryString, pars.Select(par => GetEnumerableType(par.ParameterType)).ToArray());
      }
      else
      {
        return DataSource(FileName, QueryString, pars.Select(par => par.ParameterType).ToArray());
      }
    }
    static Type GetEnumerableType(Type type)
    {
      foreach (Type intType in type.GetInterfaces())
      {
        if (intType.IsGenericType
            && intType.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(IEnumerable<>))
        {
          return intType.GetGenericArguments()[0];
        }
      }
      return null;
    }
    IEnumerable<object[]> DataSourceAsEnumerable(string fileName, string selectString, Type[] parameterTypes)
    {
      string connectionString = string.Format(connectionTemplate, GetFullFilename(fileName));
      IDataAdapter adapter = new OleDbDataAdapter(selectString, connectionString);
      DataSet dataSet = new DataSet();

      List<object[]> rows = new List<object[]>();
      try
      {
        adapter.Fill(dataSet);

        foreach (DataRow row in dataSet.Tables[0].Rows)
          rows.Add(ConvertParameters(row.ItemArray, parameterTypes));
      }
      finally
      {
        IDisposable disposable = adapter as IDisposable;
        disposable.Dispose();
      }

      object[] columns = new object[parameterTypes.Length];
      for (int i = 0; i < parameterTypes.Length; i++)
      {
        columns[i] = rows.Select(r => r[i]).ToList();
      }
      List<object[]> rv = new List<object[]>();
      rv.Add(columns.ToArray());

      return rv;
    }
    IEnumerable<object[]> DataSource(string fileName, string selectString, Type[] parameterTypes)
    {
      string connectionString = string.Format(connectionTemplate, GetFullFilename(fileName));
      IDataAdapter adapter = new OleDbDataAdapter(selectString, connectionString);
      DataSet dataSet = new DataSet();

      try
      {
        adapter.Fill(dataSet);

        foreach (DataRow row in dataSet.Tables[0].Rows)
          yield return ConvertParameters(row.ItemArray, parameterTypes);
      }
      finally
      {
        IDisposable disposable = adapter as IDisposable;
        disposable.Dispose();
      }
    }
    static string GetFullFilename(string filename)
    {
      string executable = new Uri(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().CodeBase).LocalPath;
      return Path.GetFullPath(Path.Combine(Path.GetDirectoryName(executable), filename));
    }

    static object[] ConvertParameters(object[] values, Type[] parameterTypes)
    {
      object[] result = new object[values.Length];

      for (int idx = 0; idx < values.Length; idx++)
        result[idx] = ConvertParameter(values[idx], idx >= parameterTypes.Length ? null : parameterTypes[idx]);

      return result;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Converts a parameter to its destination parameter type, if necessary.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="parameter">The parameter value</param>
    /// <param name="parameterType">The destination parameter type (null if not known)</param>
    /// <returns>The converted parameter value</returns>
    static object ConvertParameter(object parameter, Type parameterType)
    {
      if ((parameter is double || parameter is float) &&
          (parameterType == typeof(int) || parameterType == typeof(int?)))
      {
        int intValue;
        string floatValueAsString = parameter.ToString();

        if (Int32.TryParse(floatValueAsString, out intValue))
          return intValue;
      }

      return parameter;
    }


  }

}
```